# Web Scraping for tables in multiple pages using Beautifulsoup

Tags: python, python-3.x, web-scraping, beautifulsoup

I am trying to scrape a table from multiple pages for different weeks, however I keep on getting the results from this url https://www.boxofficemojo.com/weekly/2018W52/ , here's the code I am using:

```
import requests
from requests import get
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np
from time import sleep
from random import randint
import re

pages = np.arange(2015,2016)
week = ['01','02','03','04','05','06','07','08','09']
week1 = np.arange(10,11)
for x in week1:
    week.append(x)
week


mov = soup.find_all("table", attrs={"class": "a-bordered"})
print("Number of tables on site: ",len(mov))

all_rows= []
all_rows= []
for page in pages:
    for x in week:
        url = requests.get('https://www.boxofficemojo.com/weekly/'+str(page)+'W'+str(x)+'/')
        soup = BeautifulSoup(url.text, 'lxml')
        mov = soup.find_all("table", attrs={"class": "a-bordered"})
        table1 = mov[0]
        body = table1.find_all("tr")
        head = body[0] 
        body_rows = body[1:]
        sleep(randint(2,10))
        for row_num in range(len(body_rows)): 
            row = [] 
            for row_item in body_rows[row_num].find_all("td"): 
                aa = re.sub("(\xa0)|(\n)|,","",row_item.text)
                row.append(aa)
                all_rows.append(row)
                print('Page', page, x)
```

Answer (score 0):

Assuming you want 52 weeks from each year why not generate the links in advance then use pandas to retrieve the table, create a list of such dataframes and concatenate those into a final dataframe?

```
import pandas as pd

def get_table(url):
    year = int(url[37:41])
    week_yr = int(url[42:44])
    df = pd.read_html(url)[0] 
    df['year'] = year
    df['week_yr'] = week_yr
    return df
    
years = ['2015','2016']
weeks = [str(i).zfill(2) for i in range(1, 53)]
base = 'https://www.boxofficemojo.com/weekly'
urls = [f'{base}/{year}W{week}' for week in weeks for year in years]
results = pd.concat([get_table(url, int(url.split('/')[-1][:4])) for url in urls])
```

---

You might then look at ways of speeding things up e.g.

```
from multiprocessing import Pool, cpu_count
import pandas as pd

def get_table(url):
    year = int(url[37:41])
    week_yr = int(url[42:44])
    df = pd.read_html(url)[0] 
    df['year'] = year
    df['week_yr'] = week_yr
    return df
     
if __name__ == '__main__':
    
    years = ['2015','2016']
    weeks = [str(i).zfill(2) for i in range(1, 53)]
    base = 'https://www.boxofficemojo.com/weekly'
    urls = [f'{base}/{year}W{week}' for week in weeks for year in years]

    with Pool(cpu_count()-1) as p:
        results = p.map(get_table, urls)

    final = pd.concat(results)
    print(final)
```

Comment: Hi, it would be nice to hear  if this worked?